# Quick state feedback controller question

Tags: feedback, speed, linear, controller, state-space

If two estimators where used in a state feedback system, one with error dynamics poles at -10 and -9 and another one at -80 and -90.

Which system will give you a better overall performance?

Comment: What is your criteria for "better"? What factors are considered when using the term "overall"?

Comment: The further the poles are away from the origin the faster the system dynamics will occur. So I believe poles at -80 and -90  would give you faster dynamic performance. Its not possible to answer you question about better performance, without knowing what better is. Usually you want your estimators poles to be faster than your controllers poles.